# Как правильно вернуть и выполнить javascript-код из php скрипта в javascript-e

Tags: jquery, ajax

Мой js скрипт обращается к php скрипту и получает от него в обратку некий js код, который необходимо выполнить на стороне клиента. Пытаюсь сделать что то типа lazy initialize. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать логически? Весь полученный с сервера javascrip-код в onsuccess моего ajax-а исполнить в `eval`? Или получить код из php в виде DOM элемента `<script>Мой js-код с сервера</script>` и вставить этот элемент в DOM? Во втором случае даже если этот `<script></script>` потом удалить из DOM - все равно он остается в памяти: функции объявленные в нем вызываются. Как правильно логику построить? Как такие решения реализуются?

Comment: обычно пересылаются данные, а не js код

Comment: Да, но если мне необходимо выполнить набор действий который формируется в пхп в зависимости от каких то фактор ов, например включить слой, переместить его, добавить в него текст с картинкой и т.д.? Это не просто данные в массиве, это набор кода к исполнению. Я понимаю что это все можно сделать разместив функции на стороне клиента, но тогда очень много всего приходится грузить сразу, а я хочу отдавать клиенту необходимый код по факту потребности в нем